# Is there known way to add new syntax features to Protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Protobuf provides `service` keyword that defines rpc-interface of one application.
I also want to use concept of entity which means that is part of service (one service contains multiple entities). Each entity type has own unique identifier that gives possibility to address different entities in service.

I would like to use proto like this
message UserReq {
string username = 1;
string password = 2;
}

```
message RegReq {
    uint8 result_code = 1;
}

message RemoteEntityInterface
{
    MyEntity entity = 1;
}

message GiveItemResult
{
    uint8 result_code = 1;
}



service MyService {
    rpc RegisterUser (UserReq) returns (RegReq) {}

    rpc Login(UserReq) returns (RemoteEntityInterface) {}
}

entity MyEntity
{
    rpc GiveItem (GiveItemReq) returns (GiveItemResult) {} 
}
```

As you can see in example, I used unknown for protobuf keyword `entity`, this keyword means that `MyService` can return the interface to some remote object (`MyEntity`) by using `Login` remote method.

What are the ways to do this? (maybe write plugin or known way to modify source code of protobuf). Or maybe there are more flexible solutions than protobuf?

I also would like to use multiple parameters per one rpc; adding java-like attributes to rpc; service and entity; and data-model for entity (variables/fields) to add real-time replication support from entity to another service.

I think it is very flexible for services in game-development.

Answer (score 1):

The only official way to extend `.proto` syntax is to define [custom options](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#customoptions).

For example, you could have something like:

```
extend google.protobuf.ServiceOptions {
  optional bool is_entity = 123456;
}

service MyEntity
{
    option (is_entity) = true;
    rpc GiveItem (GiveItemReq) returns (GiveItemResult) {} 
}
```

The default code generator will not do anything special with this option, but you can access it from your own code and from a `protoc` plugin if you write one.